# What is the difference between id and class in html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to know what is the exact difference between id and class in html and css.

I read somewhere that ids are unique and there can be only one element with corresponding id, and classes can be applied to many elements.

But I think this is wrong I have a code in which I have applied a single id to two elements.

```html
<link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="header">

<p id="header2">Poster</p>

<p id="header2">Hello World</p>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is my css code

```css
 
 p#header2{
 background-color:white;
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 margin-left:25%;
 margin-right:25%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:50px;
}
```

Could anyone please explain me???

Comment: The browser will not crash and burn if you apply the same id twice. You're still not supposed to do it. Easiest example: it breaks the Javascript call `document.getElementById('header2')`, it will never find the second item. You're simply asking for random problems, because ids are *expected* to only exist once.

Comment: There and a ton of questions like this around the site, search before posting. Also there are even more resources on this all over the web as it is a very common and basic knowledge .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[Explanation](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)** in detail.

Use a **class** when you want to consistently style multiple elements throughout the page/site. Use the **ID** when you have a single element on the page that will take the style. **class** is a type of item and **id** is the unique name of an item.

### EDIT:

**CSS doesn't care**

Regarding `CSS`, there is nothing you can do with an `ID` that you can't do with a `Class` and vice versa. I remember when I was first learning `CSS` and I was having a problem, sometimes I would try and troubleshoot by switching around these values. Nope. `CSS` doesn't care.

**Javascript cares**

`JavaScript` people are already probably more in tune with the differences between `classes` and `ID's`. JavaScript depends on there being only one page element with any particular, or else the commonly used `getElementById` function wouldn't be dependable. For those familiar with `jQuery`, you know how easy it is to add and remove `classes` to page elements. It is a native and built in function of `jQuery`. Notice how no such function exists for `ID's`. It is not the responsibility of `JavaScript` to manipulate these values, it would cause more problems than it would be worth.

### EDIT2:

The [Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) clearly shows that HTML required the **ID** attribute to be unique in a page:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document. If you have several elements with the same **ID**, your **HTML** is not valid.

So in `JavaScript`, `getElementById()` should only ever return one element. You can't make it return multiple elements.

Well, you can have more than one element with the same ID, but you shouldn't - because the consequences of doing so is unpredictable, due to differences between browsers.

Comment: Afaik, js will not crash but simple return the first element (wrt dom traversal) with a matching id attribute, ignoring all others. Still not recommend to violate the uniqueness contract, of course.

Answer (score 0):

ID: Id name must have 1.

```
<link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="header"> // ID
<p id="header2">Poster</p>
<p id="header2">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Class: have multi tag using the same class name. And you can apply style for all class have name is "name".

```
<p class = "name">abcdef</p>
<image class = "name">......</image>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is *meant* to be unique and should contain a single identifier. The `class` attribute may contain a space-separated list of class identifiers allowing for cumulative application of css rules.

This is notwithstanding to css engines that do not complain on double ids.

Answer (score 0):

It's right:

The id of an element should be unique in the entire dom. 
The class can be applied to multiple elements.

In css if you use this syntax

```
.yourClass {
    color: white;
}
```

every element with class="yourClass" have the style color: white.

The id HAVE to be unique for different reason. The thing first jump into my mind its the use of jquery where you identify dom elements with the ID

Comment: kkkkk got it. Its all about javascript, Dom and CSS.

Comment: CSS doesn:t care but javascript does. If you are using getElementbyId it cant find the second element but in case of CSS it doen:t matter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - id is the one that can be used only once and it will be unique. Scripts mostly use id's but it doesn't mean that id will only be used with js and not css. You can used a id as selector to in css.

While classes when two or more divs have the same styling so use class instead of increasing lines of codes.